# UITableView has no scrolling

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a UIViewController which uses the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. I have created UITableView with about 20 custom UITableViewCells and not all those UITableViewCells fit on the screen. Naturally you would think that it is possible to scroll to the bottom and see the other UITableViewCells but it doesn't detect the scrolling at all so I can't see the bottom items.

My AppDelegate has a UINavigationController and I just added it with

`[window addSubview:navigationController.view]`

The View Controller inside the Navigation Controller implements a

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

All I am simply doing is creating a UINavigationController application so by default the UITableView properties should be the default ones.

My MainViewController XIB has

- View

  - Table View
  - Table View Cell
  - Table View Cell
  - Table View Cell
  - another 15 Table View Cell

From the above I'm not sure how I've modified the default UITableView as I have not configured it in any way.

The UITableView renders as I want it to, but when I want to see the bottom UITableViewCells it just doesn't scroll at all.

Comment: What happens when you explicitly set the UITableView height? Any change in scrolling ability when you do that?

Comment: I'm not using any XIB files so not sure where to set the height.

Comment: tableView.bounds.size.height = [somevalue];

Comment: Check if userInteractionEnabled on table view is YES. Care to tell which way you're added cells to table view?

Comment: I've added more information above to pinpoint the issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My checklist in this case:

- is tableview scrollEnabled == YES?
- tableView.contentSize.width != tableView.bounds.size.width && tableView.contentSize.height != tableView.bounds.size.height;
- interface orientation is correct?
- There aren't any invisibe UIView or subclass over the tableview.

Comment: how do I check these properties without using XIB's?

Comment: after checking some of the width's and height's of the UIView & UITableView, it turns out that either the UITableView was much larger than the UIView so it wasn't scrolling at all.

Comment: And I had to add that line self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES because without it, I had to click two times in the cell (only after scrolling).

Comment: Checking scrollEnabled property for tableView helped me :)